# Отправить массив на сервер

Tags: jquery, html5, javascript

Получаю список файлов с телефона, и дальше мне нужно отправить данные на сервер, но так как данных у меня не одна штука они отсылаются все по отдельности, как мне собрать их до кучи? Отправляю при помощи jQuery вот таким макаром:

```
    function listResults(entries) {
    dir_i = 0;
    file_i = 0;
    imageURI = entries[0].toURL(entry.name);

    options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    options.fileKey = "text";
    options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    //alert(options.fileName);
    options.mimeType = "text/plain";
    params = new Object();

    entries.forEach(function (entry) {
        if (entry.isDirectory) {
            params.dir_[dir_i] = entry.name;
            dir_i++;
        } else {
            params.file_[file_i] = entry.name;
            file_i++;
        }
    });

    options.params = params;
    $.post("http://91.228.199.95/ksiywFac63f2hs/userfotos.php", { dir:options },
        function (data) {
            // alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        });
}
```

**entry.name** - список названий файлов который я получаю при помощи DirectoryReader'a

Comment: что-то не очень ясный кусок кода, может поэтому минусуют

Comment: кода очень много, это кусок который отправляет данные на сервер по этому я только его и оставил.

Comment: *Каким макаром* вы поняли что данные не пришли?

Comment: в лог файле ничего не отображается, если данные приходят там пишет какие.

Comment: Каким образом вы проверяете данные? что, на момент отправки, содержит переменная `result`? Или это кастинг на битву экстрасенсов?

Comment: entry.name содержит список папок которые я должен отправить на сервер, request это контейнер который содержит все эти данные в одной переменной, но как по мне это не правильно... может есть другие идеи?

Comment: @dajver - уже лучше, еще бы отступы поправить

Comment: поправил, правда код другой, я немного видоизменил после последнего раза его

Comment: Что-то я не уверен, что вы хотите именно это:

    if(entry.isDirectory) {
      params.dir_[dir_i] = entry.name;
      dir_i++;    
    } else { 
      params.file_[file_i] = entry.name;
      file_i++;
    }
Как я понимаю, вы хотите сделать что-то типа

    if(entry.isDirectory) {
      params['dir_' + dir_i] = entry.name;
      dir_i++;    
    } else { 
      params['file_' + file_i] = entry.name;
      file_i++;
    }

Кстати - с такими данными неудобно работать.
Ну и самое главное - откройте уже для себя JSON :)

PS: невозможность редактирования комментариев уже достала, манал я

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может вы хотите вот так: ( инициализация `dir_i`, `file_i`, `params`, `options` вынесены в `listResults`, отправка данных на сервер - тоже)

```
function listResults(entries) {
    dir_i = 0;
    file_i = 0;
    imageURI = entries[0].toURL(entry.name);

    options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    options.fileKey = "text";
    options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    //alert(options.fileName);
    options.mimeType = "text/plain";
    params = new Object();

    entries.forEach(function (entry) {
        if (entry.isDirectory) {
            params.dir_[dir_i] = entry.name;
            dir_i++;
        } else {
            params.file_[file_i] = entry.name;
            file_i++;
        }
    });

    options.params = params;
    $.post("http://91.228.199.95/ksiywFac63f2hs/userfotos.php", { dir:options },
        function (data) {
            // alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        });
}
```

А то что то вы много под `forEach` запихнули...

Comment: делаю console.log(options); и в лог ничего не уходит, а там по идее должны быть строка со списком папок. В чем ошибка?

Comment: Да, мне кажется беда в том что forEach в другом потоке идёт? или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: та нет, тут не понятно в чем ошибка, я пишу все это в еклипсе с плагином фонГеп который вообще не понятно какие функции обрабатывает, а какие нет. И ошибки не понятные выдает, сижу уже долго с этой проблемой, отправкой списка...

Comment: А может есть что нить типа entries.forEach(function(entry){...}).done(function ...); ? Ну и я бы имена дал бы немного другие options и params - а то юзаем как глобальную переменную, мало ли кто подтирает

Comment: такого нету, вот это весь код который как бы должен принять список, дальше определить файл это или папка, сформировать строку и отправить на сервер.

Comment: Расставь алерты в форече, после него, чтобы понять ход работы кода. Вам надо выяснить несколько моментов:
1. Что forEach выполняется
2. Что forEach выполняется в том же потоке а не асинхронно
3. Что на выходе params и options.params не ломаются

Comment: с уверенностью могу сказать что options и params крошатся на выходе... вывод в консоль дает токо [object Object]

Comment: так консоль и ничего другого не скажет для объекта....